# Creating orbiting weapon sprite with JS canvas creates animation errors/glitches

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, rotation

I am trying to make a game in which a player has an equippable weapon. As of now, I have set this weapon to be an image of a bow, and I want to have said weapon to move around the player while facing the mouse. This is similar to [buildroyale.io](https://www.loom.com/share/a87704118bb64498b086977530ecf71b), where the player rotates along with his weapon to face the mouse.

As of now, with the help of @Justin, I've got the bow rotating (somewhat) on the screen. It only shows up when the left click is down, as desired, but does not rotate as expected. Here is a clip showcasing how it moves: [clip](https://www.loom.com/share/a87704118bb64498b086977530ecf71b)

Here is the code I use:

```
    class EventHandler {

    equip_weapon() {

        if (holding) {

            player.weapon = player.bag.slot_1;

            canv.globalAlpha = 1;
            player.weapon.equip();
            player.weapon.update();
        
        }

    }

}

class Weapon {

    image_path;

    constructor(image_path) {

        this.x = player.x + 30;
        this.y = player.y + 30;
        this.width = 120;
        this.height = 120;
        this.angle = 0;
        this.distance = 50;
        this.image = image_path;

    }

    equip() {

        this.angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.y, mouse.x - this.x)
        canv.save();
        canv.translate(this.x, this.y);
        canv.rotate(this.angle);
        canv.drawImage(this.image, this.distance, -this.height/2, this.width, this.height);
        canv.restore();  

    }

    update() {

        this.x = player.x + player.width / 2;
        this.y = player.y + player.height / 2;

    }

}
```

---

```
bow = new Weapon(bow_image);
player.bag.slot_1 = bow;

aim_bounds = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
```

---

class Player {

```
constructor() {

    this.name = null;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.skin = player_sheet;
    this.can_move = true;
    this.is_moving = false;
    this.width = 68;
    this.height = 68;
    this.scale = 1;
    this.x = 566;
    this.y = 316;
    this.direction = facing.down;
    this.frame = 0;
    this.shadow_offset = 25;
    this.frame_rate = 10;
    this.health = 100;
    this.clip_amount = 10;
    this.weapon = null;

    // Player inventory
    this.bag = {

        slot_1 : null,
        slot_2 : null,
        slot_3 : null,
        slot_4 : null,
        slot_5 : null,
        offhand : null,
        armor : null

    }

    this.is_menu_open = false;

    console.log("Player constructed!");

}

update() {

    // Animation updates
    if (game.tick % this.frame_rate == 0 && this.is_moving && !this.is_menu_open) {

        this.frame += 68;

        if (this.frame >= 272) { this.frame = 0; }

    } else if (!this.is_moving) { this.frame = 0; }

    // Movement updates
    if (this.can_move) {

        if (controller.up) { this.direction = facing.up; this.y -= this.speed; this.is_moving = true; }

        else if (controller.down) { this.direction = facing.down; this.y += this.speed; this.is_moving = true; }

        else if (controller.left) { this.direction = facing.left; this.x -= this.speed; this.is_moving = true; }

        else if (controller.right) { this.direction = facing.right; this.x += this.speed; this.is_moving = true; }

        if (!controller.up && !controller.down && !controller.left && !controller.right) { this.is_moving = false; }
        
    }
    
    // Checks
    if (this.is_menu_open) { this.can_move = false; } else { this.can_move = true; }

    document.getElementById("health_bar").value = this.health;

    if (this.is_menu_open) { menu.style.display = "block"; } else { menu.style.display = "none"; }

}

animate() {

    //  Player shadow
    canv.drawImage(player_shadow, this.x, this.y + this.shadow_offset);

    // Player
    canv.globalAlpha = 1;
    canv.drawImage(player_sheet, (sprite.x + this.frame), (sprite.y * this.direction), 
                                 sprite.width, sprite.height, 
                                 this.x, this.y, 
                                 this.width, this.height);

}
}
```

Here is a download to my current code in case you need more to debug: [game.zip](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gck6cxyhe14z4ay/fire.zip/file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I handle this is to make sure my image is first oriented correctly. In my case my bow image would look like this (ignore the quality). Just see that it faces right.

[image]

In the draw function I use `translate()` to position the image and I use the `x` and `y` inside the `drawImage(img, x, y, w, h)` to draw the image centered along the top edge of the canvas. The `x` (set to 50 in this example) position is essentially the radius of the image rotation and the `y` is just to center my bow's arrow on the y axis of the canvas.

Using `Math.atan2()` I can rotate the image

```
this.angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.y, mouse.x - this.x)
```

In this snippet I have two lines that are commented out. If you uncomment them you will better see what is happening.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

let mouse = {x: 10, y: 10}
let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  mouse.x = e.x - canvasBounds.x
  mouse.y = e.y - canvasBounds.y
})

let bow = new Image();
bow.src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/g5Sr3HmGZgWx07sRQMvgvtxZ-ErhWNT0_asFdhLIlw-EQMTuUq3BV3YY8d5rrIrZBiJ-Uo2l836Qlmr8dmaCi-dcCCqN6veS6xnE8jSrmdtRtZKnmF5FQ5aTxuVBgB28n6ICoxSlpA=w2400";

class Weapon {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 200;
    this.y = 200;
    this.w = 60;
    this.h = 60;
    this.angle = 0
  }
  draw() {
    this.angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.y, mouse.x - this.x)
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    //ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgrey';
    //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(bow, 50, -this.h/2, this.w, this.h)
    ctx.restore();  
  }
}

let bowArrow = new Weapon();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  bowArrow.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

UPDATE:

Here is what I changed in your files and it works well on my end.

`engine.controller.js` change `mousemove` and add listener for resize. I'm also pretty sure there's a way you can get rid of the `getMouse` function since the listener below gets mouse coordinates for you.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  mouse_position = event
  mouse.x = event.x - canvas_bounds.x;
  mouse.y = event.y - canvas_bounds.y;
})

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  canvas_bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
})
```

`engine.eventhandler.js`

```
class Weapon {

    image_path;

    constructor(image_path) {

        this.x = player.x + player.width/2;
        this.y = player.y + player.height/2;
        this.w = 60;
        this.h = 60;
        this.angle = 0;
        this.image = image_path;

    }

    equip() {
        this.x = player.x + player.width/2;
        this.y = player.y + player.height/2;
        this.angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.y, mouse.x - this.x)
        canv.save();
        canv.translate(this.x, this.y);
        canv.rotate(this.angle);
        canv.drawImage(this.image, 50, -this.h/2, this.w, this.h);
        canv.restore();  

    }

}
```

`engine.main.js`

```
function setup() {

    game = new Game;
    player = new Player;
    controller = new Controller;
    event_handler = new EventHandler;
    canvas.width = 1200;
    canvas.height = 700;
    canvas_bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    //  REMOVE LATER
    bow = new Weapon(bow_image);
    player.bag.slot_1 = bow;

    document.getElementById("bag").style.display = "block";

}
```

`engine.setup.js`

```
// Weapon stuff
var weapon_equiped = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let mouse = {

    x : 10,
    y : 10

}
let canvas_bound;
var mouse_position, holding;
var rect, mouse_x, mouse_y;

...and
//you have a space between canvas. height in both fillRect
canv.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas. height);
```

I think that's all I changed. Pretty sure you can use your mouse_x or the mouse.x but you probably don't need both in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! This is almost perfect! However, it seems my reproduction of your example causes some issues. Could you please help me out once more? The bow is not rotating as easily as yours is, and my mouse has to travel all the way to the corner of my canvas to make a full circle. I've updated my original post with more information.

Comment: If I have time today after work I will look at it. I can la ready see it has something to do with the way you are translating you canvas and/or possibly the `contrain()` function. May be other things you've done for positioning also. You'll see if you do not subtract `canvas_bounds` from `mouse.x/y`, in the `mousemove` listener, it already feels better but not perfect. I notice you are translating in the CSS and also compensating by positioning things with a negative value. The mouse position is incorrect because of one or more of these things.

Comment: Also be sure to update `Weapon` x and y values in the equip() method so the weapon actually follows the player when you move him. `this.x = player.x + player.width/2; this.y = player.y + player.height/2;` then use the x value in `drawImage()` to get the distance from the player you want the weapon.

Comment: Looks like canvas_bounds only updates once and its before the size is set. Console.log it and you'll see the parameters are not correct. You should set it inside your `setup` function `canvas_bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();` so it gets the correct width and height. There's a couple other small things I found also that I'll post after work.

Comment: Got it, I've tried your suggested changes. It seems better now, however, the bow does not adjust to the mouse position when the cursor is near the player. Only when the cursor is farther away from the player and bow does it align correctly. Additionally, I have switched from checking mouse presses on thee canvas to checking with the entire window, so that the bow can be aimed off of the canvas. https://www.loom.com/share/a87704118bb64498b086977530ecf71b

Comment: I added an update. I don't see any issues on my end with these changes.